# nodeJS - Passport with JWTStrategy and existing JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

It's driving me nuts and I think it is simple, but maybe I'm missing something.

So I have this wonderful piece of code here:

```
oauthClient.code.getToken(req.originalUrl).then( result => { 
   console.log("Token: " + result.accessToken); /// => asdj9823dn2ddas...
   //configure passport - use an existing JWT
   var jwtStrategy = new JWTStrategy({
      jwtFromRequest: "bearer " + result.accessToken,
      secretOrKey: XSUAA_CREDENTIALS.verificationkey /// the public key
   });                
   passport.use(jwtStrategy);
 });
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.authenticate('JWT', { session: true }));
```

Who is fetching a JWT in. The console is also telling me that I have result.accessToken filled with my JWT. Now I want to use this existing JWT to bind against my passport with jwtStrategy.
I added "bearer" before the token, also did try it without.
I used the clientsecret and the public key, both not letting me win.

Some ideas, how I can use the JWT Strategy with an JWT coming from somewhere not existing in the header / query / body so the [known extractors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt#extracting-the-jwt-from-the-request) are not usable?!

Thx for any input to this!

Comment: This looks to me like you were using the same jwt for all users? I'ts a bit confusing, because it looks to me like you're mixing setup and validation?

Comment: Switched to passport-oauth2 strategy. So I have 2 strategies in place. Thx :)